# CouchDB document update handler truncating URL parameters, despite example from documentation

Tags: couchdb

According to the documents here: https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers#Request

I can specify an update handler that accepts query string parameters. eg. (straight from the docs):

```
handlerName: function(doc, req) {
    var field = req.query.field;
    var value = req.query.value;
    var message = 'set ' + field + ' to ' + value;
    doc[field] = value;
    return [doc, message];
}
```

However when I look at the req object, there is no query.value field. My cURL command looks like this:

```
curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/map_reduce2/_design/mp2/_update/test/1?field=THEFIELD&value=THEVALUE
```

And the resultant document looks like this:

```
{
   "_id": "1",
   "_rev": "24-06f05b375e4da9ec2fc88e28711fff7d",
   "x": {
       "info": {
           "db_name": "map_reduce2",
           "doc_count": 30,
           "doc_del_count": 4,
           "update_seq": 168,
           "purge_seq": 0,
           "compact_running": false,
           "disk_size": 970856,
           "data_size": 187724,
           "instance_start_time": "1461749557106546",
           "disk_format_version": 6,
           "committed_update_seq": 168
       },
       "id": "1",
       "uuid": "cb9251557f16b50c26ef2abd8200a727",
       "method": "PUT",
       "requested_path": [
           "map_reduce2",
           "_design",
           "mp2",
           "_update",
           "test",
           "1?field=THEFIELD"
       ],
       "path": [
           "map_reduce2",
           "_design",
           "mp2",
           "_update",
           "test",
           "1"
       ],
       "raw_path": "/map_reduce2/_design/mp2/_update/test/1?field=THEFIELD",
       "query": {
           "field": "THEFIELD"
       },
       "headers": {
           "Accept": "*/*",
           "Host": "127.0.0.1:5984",
           "User-Agent": "curl/7.43.0"
       },
       "body": "undefined",
       "peer": "127.0.0.1",
       "form": {
       },
       "cookie": {
       },
       "userCtx": {
           "db": "map_reduce2",
           "name": null,
           "roles": [
           ]
       },
       "secObj": {
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: If you're trying this in the shell, maybe try wrapping the URL in quotes. The `?` and `&` might be special characters for your shell.

Comment: Thanks. that works. I am using BASH on OS X